# Combining attributes in spaCy's Matcher

Tags: nlp, spacy

Is it possible to combine different attributes in spaCy's matcher?

For example, we can match a lemma:

```
{"LEMMA": "mylemma"}
```

and we can match a lowercase string:

```
{"LOWER": "mylowercasestring"}
```

Is it possible to match a LOWER LEMMA?

EDIT:

At least when using the German model (de_core_news_sm), lemmas are not lowercased. Suppose I have the German phrase "des Richters", whose lemma sequence is "der Richter" -- I want a matcher to match lemmas independent of case, so that it matches the lemmas "Richter" and "richter" or any other case variation.

Comment: Not sure i understand the confusion, but token features are independent, so you have to specify the values of each one to constrain your match, e.g. [{'LOWER': 'is', 'LEMMA': 'be'}]. As an aside, as far as I know the LEMMA attribute is lower-cased by default.

Comment: Please see clarifications on my confusion